# A fast and efficient, not-so complex word content filter

Tags: python, list, spam

Without getting into bayesian-level content classification project, I'm trying to make a very simple profanity filter for twitter accounts.

In essense, I just **join all of a user's tweets into one large text blob** and **run the content against my filter,** which in essence works like this:

```
badwords = ['bad', 'worse', 'momwouldbeangry', 'thousandsofperversesayings', 'xxx', 'etc']

s = 'Get free xxx etc'

score = 0

for b in badwords:
    if b in s:
        score = score+1
```

I have a 3k list of bad words (what a perverted world we live in!) and ideally I'd like to create a score based not only on word occurance, but how many times each word occurs. So if the word  occurs twice, the score would increment twice.

The score generator above is extremely simple but re-evaluates the string thousands of times, plus it does not increment the way I'd like.

How can this be adjusted for performance and accuracy?

Comment: This approach is extremely vulnerable to the *"Scunthorpe problem"*...

Comment: Use KMP or regular experssions

Comment: Use `collections.Counter` on your text, and then check which words in the counter appear in your badwords list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `len(badwords) == 3000`, therefore with `tweet_words = len(s.split()))` it is that `len(tweet_words) < len(badwords)`; hence

```
for b in badwords:
    if b in s:
        score = score+1
```

is really inefficient.

First thing to do: make `badwords` a `frozenset`. That way, it's much faster to look for an ocurrence of something in it.

Then, search for words in `badwords`, not the other way around:

```
for t_word in tweet_words
    if t_word in badwords:
        score = score+1
```

then, be a bit more functional!

```
score_function = lambda word: 0 if len(word) < 3 or (word not in badwords) else 1
score = lambda tweet: sum(score(lower(word)) for word in tweet.split())
```

which will be faster than the full loops, because python needs to construct and destruct less temporary contexts (that's technically a bit misleading, but you save a lot of cpython pyObject creations).

Comment: Using a list with sum is not needed. `sum(score(lower(word)) for word in tweet.split())`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, I always forget to "delete" the list construction from my mental plan how my code should work (that pretty well reflects how my mind constructs such code snippets). I'll edit :)

Answer (score 0):

If the each `badword` cannot be a substring and you want a count for each word you could use a dict, you would also need to lower and strip any punctuation from the words in your users tweets:

```
from string import punctuation
badwords = dict.fromkeys(('bad', 'worse', 'momwouldbeangry', 'thousandsofperversesayings', 'xxx', 'etc'),0)

s = 'Get free xxx! etc!!'

for word in s.split():
    word = word.lower().strip(punctuation)
    if word in badwords:
        badwords[word] += 1


print(badwords)
print(sum(badwords.values()))
{'momwouldbeangry': 0, 'xxx': 1, 'etc': 1, 'bad': 0, 'thousandsofperversesayings': 0, 'worse': 0}
2
```

If you don't care what words appear just the count:

```
from string import punctuation
badwords = {'bad', 'worse', 'momwouldbeangry', 'thousandsofperversesayings', 'xxx', 'etc'}

s = 'Get free xxx! etc!!'

print(sum( word.lower().strip(punctuation)in badwords for word in s.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `collections.Counter`;

```
In [1]: text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"""

In [2]: badwords = ['in', 'ex']

In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [9]: words = text.lower().split()

In [10]: c = Counter(words)

In [11]: c
Out[11]: Counter({'ut': 3, 'in': 3, 'dolore': 2, 'dolor': 2, 'adipiscing': 1, 'est': 1, 'exercitation': 1, 'aute': 1, 'proident,': 1, 'elit,': 1, 'irure': 1, 'consequat.': 1, 'minim': 1, 'pariatur.': 1, 'nostrud': 1, 'laboris': 1, 'occaecat': 1, 'lorem': 1, 'esse': 1, 'quis': 1, 'anim': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'laborum': 1, 'sunt': 1, 'qui': 1, 'incididunt': 1, 'culpa': 1, 'consectetur': 1, 'aliquip': 1, 'duis': 1, 'cillum': 1, 'excepteur': 1, 'cupidatat': 1, 'labore': 1, 'magna': 1, 'do': 1, 'fugiat': 1, 'reprehenderit': 1, 'ullamco': 1, 'ad': 1, 'commodo': 1, 'tempor': 1, 'non': 1, 'et': 1, 'ex': 1, 'deserunt': 1, 'sit': 1, 'eu': 1, 'voluptate': 1, 'mollit': 1, 'eiusmod': 1, 'aliqua.': 1, 'nulla': 1, 'sed': 1, 'sint': 1, 'nisi': 1, 'enim': 1, 'veniam,': 1, 'velit': 1, 'id': 1, 'officia': 1, 'ea': 1})

In [12]: scores = [v for k, v in c.items() if k in badwords]

In [13]: scores
Out[13]: [1, 3]

In [14]: sum(scores)
Out[14]: 4
```

Comment: While I'm not sure concerning performance, this is great for providing a score system.

Comment: As you can see I'm only using a list comprehension for looping over the scores.  Creating a Counter for a 9 kB, 1374 words corpus takes 239 µs on my machine.